# How to Draw graph in ASP.NET MVC 4 using High-Charts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am trying to make a chart in MVC 4. But it's not working.I am using High-Charts.This is my action method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var title = new Title() { Text = "Workload" };

            var subtitle = new Subtitle() { Text = "workload per day" };

            var XData = new[] { "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" };
            var YData = new object[] { 195, 150, 0, 270, 0, 90, 245, 215, 350, 355, 190, 95, 0, 100, 225 };

            var xaxisTitle = new XAxisTitle { Text = "Wokload in minutes" };
            var yaxisTitle = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Time in days" };

            string serieName = "Workload per day";

            Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
                .SetTitle(title)
                .SetSubtitle(subtitle)
                .SetXAxis(new XAxis
                {
                    Categories = XData,
                    Title = xaxisTitle
                })
                .SetYAxis(new YAxis
                {
                    Title = yaxisTitle
                })
                .SetSeries(new Series
                {
                    Data = new Data(YData),
                    Name = serieName
                });

            return View(chart);

        }
```

and this is my View.

```
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<header>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts-more.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts-all.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts-3d.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
</header>

There is a graph


@(Model)
```

What is wrong with this code? This is showing nothing in the view. There is a blank page when i run it.Please someone guide me.

Comment: Open JavaScript console and copy&paste here errors. In Chrome it's ctrl+shift+J (or Options -> More Tools -> JavaScript Console).

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me Just remove the redundant Script URL and match the version of your Script file and the URL you used. for example let me show you how I used This Code. before this leave the codes inside your action as it is. do not modify it.

**The problem is your Java Script version**

[Look at this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPqtl.png)

I changed this    `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> in to   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  and <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in to 
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

now My Code is fine to run.

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine on my computer after I removed two redundant jquery links. You don't need both js and min.js files. Latter is just optimized version of  former with removed unnesessary spaces, shortened variable names, etc.

Comment: which two line should i removed please mention

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> Two of them. Also make sure you refer correct version of jquery. For example i've got 1.8.2 not 1.7.1 in my Scripts directory.

Comment: Actually, I think it's all because of wrong version number. You can have both js and min.js file. It still works this way.

Comment: not working...
Please mention two lines that you have removed .

Comment: Do you have jquery-1.5.1.min.js file in your Scripts directory? I think you need to change version number.

Comment: i am using jquery i.7.1.min.js

Comment: Then change <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-**1.5.1**.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> to <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-**1.7.1**.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Then I don't know... What errors are shown on javascript console in your browser?

Comment: Not a big deal. But it's strange, there should be some errors. My console shows me Uncaught Hightcharts error #16 for example. Your scripts haven't loaded probably.

Comment: is there any way to draw chart. If you know please tell me.

Comment: No, sorry. Don't have much experience in this area.